# Unable to click an element

Tags: seleniumbase

I'm new to seleniumbase, and I'm trying to implement the following which I located from the Copy JS Path of a Chrome Browser on Windows.The copy JS path is giving me the following query: document.querySelector("#aplicant-info-cs-state-dropdown").
Xpath or CSS selectors are unable to locate this pulldown for some reason.

Now I'm unclear about which self.click API method I need to use to trigger a simple click.

Thank you in advance.